# Unable to capture Rest API's in soapui with proxy

Tags: soapui, web-service, rest-api, proxy

I am a SoapUI Beginner, using SOAPUI(version 5.3.0) open source for API testing. I want to fetch all Rest API with a proxy. But whenever I use HTTP Monitoring Tool in soapUI to fetch all the rest APIs I am receiving Null pointer exception.

I tried the following steps:

1. Under preferences, added proxy for localhost.
2. The same proxy setting is made on Firefox browsers.
3. Launched HTTP monitor.

Now, whenever I hit a URL for any website. The website is throwing a Nullpointer exception.

I am not sure about below points:

1. If soapUI does not support capturing rest API's till now for open source.
2. If yes how can I capture the rest API's?

Comment: You might need to ask soapUI specifically.

Comment: You can simply use a free rest api testing app and just test rest api from mobile itself. Very simple and easy. Download here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rester.restapitester

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you're trying to do ***API discovery*** on some website/resource/endpoint.

Seems like SoapUI only offers this feature for SOAP web services.

If you want to do API discovery there seems to be no real way to do that programmatically/automatically due to the nature of REST APIs.

It is impossible to determine all possible endpoints without doing some kind of brute force http requests or something similar to that.

Anyway, [this link](https://nordicapis.com/api-discovery-15-ways-to-find-apis/) may be of help but it only lists some websites that offer already discovered collections of APIs.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you want to catch/record all traffic to your website? Try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for capturing the traffic as it can act as a proxy between your browser and server ("website").